# Visual C++: How to get seleted item from a listBox in IF statement?

Tags: visual-c++, if-statement, listbox, selecteditem

I've never used a listBox before, nor has Google aided me, so here is my question: How do you check if a certain item is selected in a listBox?

Pseudocode:

```
if(item X is currently selected in listBox1)
{
    //execute code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the LB_GETSEL message to the list box with the SendMessage API.

For Win32 API programming the reference you should be using is MSDN. Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485971(v=vs.85).aspx